# Latex 'fat comma'

Tags: symbols, math-operators, stmaryrd

I am looking for a 'blackboard-bold' style comma notation. In particular, is there a comma similar to the lower part in `\fatsemi` from the `stmaryrd` package? I tried to search 'fat comma', 'blackboard-bold comma', but did not get anything wanted. I am aware of using the approach similar to `\fcmp` but that looks less nice to me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilble TeX code?

Comment: The [`bbold` font](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbold) has one.

Answer (score 6):

You can grab the glyph from the `bbold` font. The style is a little bit different from that of `\fatsemi` though:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd, bbold}

\DeclareSymbolFont{bbsymbol}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbsemicolon}{\mathbin}{bbsymbol}{"3B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbcomma}{\mathbin}{bbsymbol}{"2C}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \verb|\fatsemi|:        & $a\fatsemi b$ \\
        \verb|bbold| semicolon: & $a\bbsemicolon b$ \\ 
        \verb|bbold| comma:     & $a\bbcomma b$ \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use `trimclip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd, trimclip}

\newcommand{\fatcomma}{\mathbin{\clipbox*{0 -1ex {\width} .66ex}{$\fatsemi$}}}

\begin{document}

$a\fatsemi b$

$a\fatcomma b$

\end{document}
```